# Meaning of нифига себе!

Tags: словоупотребление, сленг

What is the meaning and usage of (ну) нифига себе! Someone said it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct spelling would be "Ни фига себе!" There is also another slang version of this expression, commonly used in social networks, "фигасе".

It is an exclamation of surprise, astonishment of shock (positive or negative). It can be translated as "Oh boy", "Wow", "Holy cow", etc.

Comment: Only "wow" and "holy cow", not "no way".

Comment: "No way!" is perfectly in line with all these other exclamations when you see something cool or unbelievable. It means "There's not way this can be possible = I must be dreaming!" It was fine.